# What type of battery does a small gray Mastercraft Pocket Digital Multimeter (model 52-0051-4) require?

Tags: batteries, multimeter

Canadian Tire is a retail chain which operates only in Canada.  They're probably one of the biggest retailers of hardware and tools in the country.

One of their store brands is Mastercraft. About ten years ago, they carried a small dark-gray "Mastercraft Pocket Digital Multimeter". The model number is 52-0051-4. It cost between CAD $10 and CAD $40 or so, depending whether or not you bought it on sale.

The multimeter uses one battery. When the battery gets low, the multimeter starts giving you inaccurate readings. To replace the battery, you unscrew two screws and open the multimeter up.

Engraved on the inside of the multimeter's battery holder is a generic battery symbol, a plus sign, and a minus sign. This engraving tells you which way the battery goes. Unfortunately, there's no information printed or engraved anywhere on the outside or inside of the multimeter about which type of battery it requires. So, what type of battery does it require?

Comment: They must have learned, since 052-0728-6 does list both the battery and fuse info on the back (although definitely not worth full price).

Comment: Yes, 052-0728-6 looks like a somewhat-improved successor to the old 52-0051-4.  Unfortunately, 052-0728-6 still uses a tiny A23 battery. It's probably wiser to buy a bigger multimeter for which replacement batteries are easier to find.

Comment: *shrug* Almost any dollar store I go to carries A23 batteries here.

Comment: You may be able to find A23 batteries in almost any dollar store, but you might not be able to find them in your home or garage. It's more practical to use a multimeter which takes ordinary 9V smoke-alarm batteries; this lessens the number of types of battery that you have to keep in stock at home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This multimeter requires one single [A23 alkaline battery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A23_battery). This type of battery is occasionally also called "23A", "23AE", "GP23A", "V23GA", "8LR932", "8LR23", "MN21", "L1028", or "ANSI-1181A".

Dead alkaline batteries sometimes leak. When your old battery dies, remove it from the device before it starts leaking.